# Definition of pull-back analogous to push-forward

Tags: real-analysis, definition, vector-fields

Let $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n, V\subseteq\mathbb{R}^m$ be open subsets, and $f:U\rightarrow V$ a $C^1$ map. Let $u,v$ be vector fields on $U,V$ respectively. Then the **push-forward** $f_*u$ is equal to $v$ if and only if $u$ and $v$ are $f$-related.

The vector fields $u$ and $v$ are **$f$-related** if for all $p\in U$ and $q=f(p)$, we have $Df(p)\cdot u(p) = v(q)$.

How do we define the **pull-back**? Is it defined as the opposite of the push-forward like:

$f^*v$ is equal to $u$ if and only if $u$ and $v$ are $f$-related?

Comment: What does it mean to be $f$-related?

Comment: @Berci I just edited to add that.

Comment: @user99680 So pushing forward by $f^{-1}$ coincides with the definition I wrote, right?

Comment: @Mika H: But you need the same conditions on $f^{-1}$ as you do on $f$ to be able to pullback.

Comment: @user99680 You mean the condition that $f^{-1}$ is $C^1$, or something else?

Comment: @ Mika H: I mean that you need two vector fields X,Y ,in V,U respectively, so that X,V are $f^{-1}$-related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is a natural Riemannian metric on $\mathbb R^n$ and $\mathbb R^m$, a notion of pull back for vector fields could be defined as follows:  let $v$ be a vector field on $V$.  Then $f^*v$ is a vector field on $U$ so that for all vector fields $w$ on $U$ we have $\langle f^* v,w\rangle = \langle v, f_* w \rangle$, where $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is the inner product on either $\mathbb R^n$ or $\mathbb R^m$ as appropriate.  But since we are regarding vector fields as being dual spaces to the space of vector fields, it is more common to call them cotangent vector fields, or 1-forms.

Comment: I see, so you define it as the adjoint (by the metric) to the pushforward?

Comment: Right.  That is what you do.